# Returned array has undefined value

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am trying to return an array through async/await:

```
        app.get('/users/article/feed',checkAuthenticated,async (request,response)=>{
           try{
             function executor(){
                let articleArray=[]

                const sql="SELECT noOfArticles FROM Articles WHERE id=?"
                db.query(sql,[request.user.id], (err,result)=>{
                  if(err) throw err
                  let noOfArticles=result[0].noOfArticles
                   for(let i=1;i<=noOfArticles;i++){
                     const sql1="SELECT ?? FROM Articles WHERE id=?"
                     let index='article'+i
                     db.query(sql1,[index,request.user.id],(err,result)=>{
                       if(err) throw err
                       articleArray.push(result[0][index])
                       if(articleArray.length===noOfArticles){
                         console.log(articleArray);      //here the array is printed as expected
                         return articleArray;
                  }
             })

            }

           })
          }
          const resultArray= await executor();
          console.log(resultArray);            //here the array is undefined
          response.render('viewArticles');

    }    catch(e){
          console.log(e);
      }

     })
```

The resultArray is always undefined.
I know this is a very old question. I tried checking all the other answers in Stack Overflow but I am confused a lot about this. I am a newbie to js so I couldn't understand it properly. How can I solve this?

Comment: `executor` is using a callback based API and not returning a Promise. Does `db.query` have a Promise based alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning from inside the callback function, which won't work since `executor` doesn't wait for your queries responses. Return a Promise instead.

```js
function executor() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let articleArray = [];

        const sql = "SELECT noOfArticles FROM Articles WHERE id=?";
        db.query(sql, [request.user.id], (err, result) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            let noOfArticles = result[0].noOfArticles;
            for (let i = 1; i <= noOfArticles; i++) {
                const sql1 = "SELECT ?? FROM Articles WHERE id=?";
                let index = "article" + i;
                db.query(sql1, [index, request.user.id], (err, result) => {
                    if (err) return reject(err);
                    articleArray.push(result[0][index]);
                    if (articleArray.length === noOfArticles) {
                        console.log(articleArray); //here the array is printed as expected
                        return resolve(articleArray);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it return some result if you make the function you are calling async?

```
async function executor(){
            let articleArray=[]

            const sql="SELECT noOfArticles FROM Articles WHERE id=?"
            db.query(sql,[request.user.id], (err,result)=>{
              if(err) throw err
              let noOfArticles=result[0].noOfArticles
               for(let i=1;i<=noOfArticles;i++){
                 const sql1="SELECT ?? FROM Articles WHERE id=?"
                 let index='article'+i
                 db.query(sql1,[index,request.user.id],(err,result)=>{
                   if(err) throw err
                   articleArray.push(result[0][index])
                   if(articleArray.length===noOfArticles){
                     console.log(articleArray);      //here the array is printed as expected
                     return articleArray;
              }
         })

        }

       })
      }
```

Comment: No it doesn't return any value.The console statement is logged as Promise {undefined}

Comment: I would suggest printing objects to the console as your code works through the function. For example, at the start of the function, I would do console.log(req.user.id). Then after the first db.query, I would do console.log(result). Follow it through until you find why a result is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

When you return articleArray, you are not returning it from the executor function. Instead you are returning it from the callback that is passed into the db.query function. The `() => {}` syntax is basically shorthand for `function() {}` (although there are differences that are outside the scope of this answer).

Perhaps something like this might be helpful (note that I removed the try catch, as I believe such logging should be done at the middleware level in express, which it seems you are using):

```js
app.get('/users/article/feed', checkAuthenticated, async (request, response) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let articleArray = []

        const sql = "SELECT noOfArticles FROM Articles WHERE id=?"
        db.query(sql, [request.user.id], (err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            let noOfArticles = result[0].noOfArticles
            for (let i = 1; i <= noOfArticles; i++) {
                const sql1 = "SELECT ?? FROM Articles WHERE id=?"
                let index = 'article' + i
                db.query(sql1, [index, request.user.id], (err, result) => {
                    if (err) reject(err); // reject the promise if there is an error
                    articleArray.push(result[0][index])
                    if (articleArray.length === noOfArticles) {
                        console.log(articleArray);
                        resolve(articleArray); // resolve the promise with the value we want
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
})
```